# Error in pandas when using kwd 'sheetname=None'

Tags: python, pandas

I can properly load an excel file in pandas with:

```
wb2 = pd.read_excel(file)
```

However, when I try to load it with:

```
wb2 = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname=None)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType

This should be correct as I understand it in the docs. I can use `sheetname=0` or any other valid index number for this particular Excel file, and it returns a valid DataFrame, but `None` keeps giving this error.

I've looked at example code that uses this flag for `sheetname`, so I'm perplexed as to why it's not working. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Apparently I was running pandas version 0.15.2, which didn't allow for the 'None' option.  I upgraded to 0.16.2, and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are stuck on older versions:

```
excel_dict = {}
for sn in pd.ExcelFile('excelFile.xlsx').sheet_names:
    excel_dict[sn] = pd.read_excel('excelFile.xlsx',sheetname=sn)
```

Comment: would be better if you can add the threshold for `older version` as mentioned in the ans below